# Why is there no "break" support for flow control methods in helm template

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I have a range function but would like to break from the control if certain condition is met. Is there a way this can be achieved in helm template

UPDATE:

I have seen some related queries where conclusion is "break" is unsupported. But would like to get some official documentation OR reason in case this is not supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have some good news here! Not sure from which exact version of `helm` the update happened but you can for sure use the `break` in your templates with the newest [helm@v3.12.0](https://github.com/helm/helm/releases/tag/v3.12.0).

This is because the new version of helm bumped the `go` version to `1.20` and the `break` has been introduced in the [`text/template` in go `v1.18`](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template@go1.18).

So now you can do stuff like this:

```yaml
  {{- range $i, $e := until 10 -}}
    {{- if lt $i 5 -}}
      Less than five.
    {{- else -}}
      {{- break -}}
    {{- end -}}
  {{- end -}}
```

Happy helming!